# How to get drop down value dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, zend-form

I have a dropdown list in PHP Zend with the following code :

```
$this->addElement('select', 'target', array(
            'decorators' => $this->getElementDecorators(),
            'label' => Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Target_Platform'),
            'style' => 'width:320px;',
            'data-help' => Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Target_Platform_To_Publish_To'),
        ));
```

This has a list of about 14 values.

I am using below code in my JS file to get the CURRENT drop-down value :

```
this.temp = $('#target :selected').text();
console.dir(this.temp);
```

However the value in this variable does not changes when I select some other value in the dropdown ?
I want the variable to change **dynamically** as per the values selected by the user.

How is that possible ? 
Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.select` event to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#target").select(function(){

       console.log($(this).val());

    });

});
```

And i hope that you have included `jQuery` file

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

```
<body>

.....
// At the end of the body because JS loads Synchronously 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#target").select(function(){

           console.log($(this).val());

        });

    });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Void. 
Where do I include the script tag ? 
In the JS file ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked .

```
$('#target').on('change', function () {
       var data = {
        platform: $('#target :selected').text()
        };
      console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding `this.temp = $('#target :selected').text();` to some event( .select ), So when event get fired the desired code will get executed. From current approach , `this.temp = $('#target :selected').text();` will get executed only when the document is loaded giving the default value.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/